# Paste SQL Query output with line breaks into single Excel cell

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write SQL code that pulls data from more than one field and displays it in a single field, but on multiple lines.  The goal is outputting to Excel retaining multiple lines *in a single cell*.  Our current procedure is just using Excel to concatenate two fields into one cell with carriage returns, but I would like to have SQL do that if possible.

For example:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(100)
SET @text = 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)  + 'This is line 2.'
print @text
```

Displays this:

```
This is line 1.   
This is line 2.
```

Changing to a Select:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(100)
SET @text = 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13) + 'This is line 2.'
select @text
```

Displays this:

```
This is line 1. This is line 2.
```

I want to then copy and paste that output into Excel and have the data appear in a single cell so this is all in one cell:

```
This is line 1.   
This is line 2.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SQL query, instead of carriage returns, use:

```
   " & CHAR(10) & "
```

Have the column start with an **equals sign** and **double quote**, and end with **double quote**. So, the output from SQL would be:

```
="This is line 1." & CHAR(10) & "This is line 2."
```

Put this into Excel. This will look like a mess, until you make sure that under Format Cells you've checked 'Wrap Text', then the carriage returns will appear within the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You see the line break in the first snippet because you're looking at the Messages window in Management Studio. There were no results from that code. What you see in the 2nd snippet is how Management Studio shows you results. Think of it like a debugging view of your data. Management Studio is not a reporting tool. *The `char(13)` value **will** be there in the raw data*; it's just not shown to you in this view.

However, three issues remain.

The first issue is how you get the data to Excel. If this is a VBA macro or done via a library the creates Excel-native files directly, you're probably fine. Other options all have problems:

- If you copy/paste, you are copying from that debugging view where the line break is not present.
- If you're running a program that creates a CSV file or similar, you're relying on Excel's CSV parser, which isn't likely to handle the line break well.
- If you're using the "Results to Text" or "Results to File" feature in Management Studio, the character is there, but you're also dealing with some extra header and footer text that Excel won't handle automatically (though you could use this as a copy/paste source).

For the second issue, even in some cases where you have the `char(13)`, that's only half of a line break on Windows systems. You also need a additional `CHAR(10)` for it to show up in some situations, like this:

```
SET @text = 'This is line 1.' + char(13) + CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
```

The final issue is whether Excel will honor the line break even when it's really there. Excel cells don't like line breaks. It wants you to have that kind of data in a new row. Open up a new blank worksheet and let me know how much success you have even manually typing two lines of text into the same cell. You may need to explicitly tell Excel to wrap the text, or change the default view.

Comment: Thanks Joel for the thorough explanation.  Am using a 3rd party application that has a report builder, but is very limited, so most of the time I build and run Reports directly out of SQL and then copy/paste the results into Excel to send off to other Staff to work with them more.  Am just now starting to work with SSRS as well to work on some preformatting.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [@tysonwright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3097559/tysonwright) answer above to be clever and helpful, but for me, CHAR(10) caused two "line breaks" (ALT-Enter) to appear in the wrapped cell even when I pasted values.

So, I solved it as follows:

SQL to replace CRLF with a pipe (or any unique character of your choice) and remove any duplicates:

```
 SELECT replace(notes2,'||','|') as Notes2 from
    (
    SELECT replace(notes,char(13)+char(10),'|') as Notes2
    FROM   mytable
    ) z
```

Then in EXCEL, find-replace the pipe "|" to a line break entered as CTRL-SHIFT-J per [How to Replace Text with NewLine](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4859-excel-replace-comma-with-newline-alt-enter.html)

This made the wrapped text look as if it was entered with newlines (ALT-Enter) that I could not accomplish with any combination of char(13), char(10).

It probably can be done in VBA or formula with Replace/Subsitute using vblf, but I didn't try it.